# Get count when value is null

Tags: ssrs-2008, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

```
=iif(Len(Fields!IsAbsent.Value) = 0,count(Fields!IsAbsent.Value),0)
```

In query above I want to get the count when IsAbsent returns null. count function doesn't work when the value is null.

Answer (score 2):

```
=Sum(iif(IsNothing(Fields!.Reading.Value ), 1, 0))
```

Have no possibility to check on my own, but please try something like this.